# condition does not work on blade laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I want to load the panel if the user is logged in

and if the client is the master

But both files are loaded at runtime.

It does not run like a bet!

```
@if(Auth::check())
    @extends('panel')
@else
    @extends('master')
@endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want? To have different layouts for logged user and not logged one?

`@extends(Auth::check() ? 'panel' : 'master')`

You can't use two extends.

Two extends generate compiled views with code

```
<?php if(Auth::check()): ?>

<?php else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

You can see, that extends are not here. But in the end of it -

```
<?php echo $__env->make('panel')... ->render();
<?php echo $__env->make('master')... ->render();
```

That's why use see them both.

Comment: @hassanahmadi you can accept the answer with a check if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Try use:**
 `auth()->check(), \Auth::check(),` or remove all views in `/var/www/html/laravel-master/storage/framework/views/`.

If Auth::check() does not work, use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check() instead:

```
@if(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check())
    @extends('panel')
@else
    @extends('master')
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit your extends definition :**

Try this

```
@extends(auth()->check() ? 'panel' : 'master')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
@extends(isset(Auth::user()->id) ? 'panel' : 'master');
```